# Downloading Android source with repo

Tags: android

When I give these commands then the 2.3.7 branch gets initialized in current directory and source gets downloaded.

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.3.7_r1

repo sync
```

Thereafter if I give following command what exactly happens

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

or

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

My Questions

1. Will my earlier branch be deleted which I have downloaded with great difficulty? Cant I have multiple branches existing simultaneously?
2. If I can have more than one branch then how to access them? I dont see any directory called 2.3.7 or 4.0.1.
3. The repo directory structure is very confusing. Can anybody guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start a new repo branch within the same source code branch

```
 repo start BRANCH_NAME [PROJECT_LIST]
```

Also refer to the [following book](http://book.git-scm.com/) on how to switch and make use to features in git

Look at section on [branching and merging](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html). Create branch using repo and then git commands to move around

Comment: OK Thanks for the info. I have read through git references. I understood a bit about branches. How to use it here with repo. Right now I am synced with 2.3.7_r1 branch. Now I want to put 4.0.1_r1 branch. What command should I use with repo? Is it repo start android-4.0.1_r1 ? After this will I be able to switch branches with checkout ?

Comment: Thanks I experimented with the above command. repo start android-4.0.1_r1 --all should work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a repo init in a different directory. repo init clones the git structure specified by the manifest file 
e.g

```
android/gingerbread/repo init

android/eclair/repo init
```

Comment: This means that I would have to clone many GB each time I wanted to work on a different branch. I was kind of hoping that all the branches are contained within the same clone and I just need to change branches if I want to work on a different branch.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to sync a new branch while using the files downloaded at previous sync to save download time.

1. create a new directory
2. copy the `.repo` file (hidden) from the `old branch_folder` (gingerbread in your case) to a new directory
3. cd into that directory

Finally you can do:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
repo sync
```